# PHP Dynamic body ID from Current Page Name

Tags: php, dynamic, document-body

Hi i want a function on external php file like this or similar;

```
basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.php');
```

to replace the id of my body depending of the name of the page im on

```
ex. page : infoweb.com/info.php?page=contact
ex. body id="{bodyID}" where {bodyID} to be "contact"
```

Im sorry im not verry familiar with programing stuff but have some ideas of basics.

Comment: You can do that simply by using `id="'.$_GET['page'].'"`within an `echo`statement, or if you're using enclosures, something like `id="<?= $_GET['page']; ?>"`- not recommended to do this simply as this, without any checking of the content against a whitelist, and it won't work if there isn't a page-variable in the url, but you should get the gist of it.

Comment: all my page links are like; `name.php?page=pagename` i need a function to a external php then call that to my body `id="{bodyID}"` for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- TemplateLib.php -->
private function gameHeader($metatags = '')
{
$page = str_replace(array('/', 'game.php', '?page='), '',
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$page = $page ? $page : 'overview';
$parse['bodyID'] = $page;
return
$this->parseTemplate($this->getTemplate('general/simple_header'), $parse);
}

<!-- simple_header.php -->
<body id="{bodyID}">
```

and is a working solution for me now i will adjust the REQUEST_URI function only if is not secure i must read the web more thanks in advance, can't belive i have managed this myself with info from the web without knowledge :)